# Search function with PyGTKsourceview

Tags: python, pygtk

I'm writing a small html editor in python mostly for personal use and have integrated a gtksourceview2 object into my Python code. All the mayor functions seem to work more or less, but I'm having trouble getting a search function to work. Obvioiusly the GUI work is already done, but I can't figure out how to somehow buildin methods of the GTKsourceview.Buffer object (http://www.gnome.org/~gianmt/pygtksourceview2/class-gtksourcebuffer2.html) to actually search through the text in it.

Does anybody have a suggestion? I find the documentation not very verbose and can't really find a working example on the web.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The [reference for the C API](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtksourceview/stable/) can probably be helpful, including this chapter that I found ["Searching in a GtkSourceBuffer"](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtksourceview/stable/gtksourceview-2.0-Searching-in-a-GtkSourceBuffer.html).

As is the reference for the superclass [gtk.TextBuffer](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtktextbuffer.html)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the python doc, I couldn't find any up-to-date documentation so I stuffed it in my dropbox. Here is the [link](http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/961121/class-gtksourcebuffer2.html). What you want to look at is at is the `gtk.iter_forward_search` and `gtk.iter_backward_search` functions.